# reference to e.preventDefault

Tags: javascript, object, methods, event-handling, preventdefault

Why reference to this object's method works

```js
const obj = {
  hi: () => alert('hi')
}
obj.hi() // 'hi'

const myMethod = obj.hi
myMethod() // 'hi'
```

But reference to the event's object method does not?

```js
const link = document.querySelector('a')
link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const doNotFollowLink = e.preventDefault
  doNotFollowLink()
  alert('this line was never reached')
})
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">Click here</a>
```

Comment: read the error in the browser console

Comment: By putting the function to be called (like a callback) into its own variable: `const doNotFollowLink = e.preventDefault`, its calling context, or `this`, gets lost - `this` no longer refers to `e`. `preventDefault` needs to be called with a `this` of the event to work properly.

Comment: so `const doNotFollowLink = e.preventDefault.bind(e);`

Comment: @JaromandaX, browser console says: "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation at HTMLAnchorElement."

Comment: @JaromandaX, your code with 'bind' works, thank you!

Comment: By the way, your browser issues unhelpful errors! another reason to develop using something that is not Chromium based :p

Comment: Explanation for myself, it seems e.preventDefault() uses THIS in its implementation and it is lost when we assign it to another variable

const obj = {
  number: 5,
  showNumber: function() { alert(this.number) } 
}
obj.showNumber() // 5


const myShowNumber = obj.showNumber
myShowNumber() // undefined

const myShowNumber2 = obj.showNumber.bind(obj)
myShowNumber2() // 5